# Getting around 150MB shell limit in powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-remoting

Cross posted from https://serverfault.com/questions/752202/install-net-4-6-1-remotely-via-powershell,

Basically I am hitting all sorts of errors trying to install/run the .NET Framework upgrade because the powershell session is out of memory. Trying to install via Chocolatey, I get a 'Thread cannot start' issue. Trying via standard powershell, the exe seems to 'bomb out' on `iex` because the extractor takes up too much memory. I've also tried `Start-Process` and `iex("cmd.exe /C pathtoexe.exe")` and that also fails.

I cannot log into all N hosts and change their powershell limit as indicated here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/07/30/learn-how-to-configure-powershell-memory.aspx because I have a LARGE quantity of hosts. Hoping the community has some ideas. Script below

```
    Write-Host "Executing 'Upgrade dotnet 4.6' for $server"
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servers -Credential $credentials -ScriptBlock {
    $Url = 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/4/1/E4173890-A24A-4936-9FC9-AF930FE3FA40/NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe'
    $Exe = "net461.exe"
    $Dest = "C:\" + $Exe
    $Params = " /q"
    $client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
    $client.DownloadFile($Url,$Dest) 
    Invoke-Expression ("cmd.exe /C " + $Dest + $Params)
    }
```

Comment: Log into all hosts through Invoke-Commad and change the limits and then run though the same list again to install the .NET framework?

Comment: It doesn't appear that I can run the command to change the limits remotely. 

```WSManFault
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (WSManFault:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : 63.135.166.166
 
    Message = Access is denied. 
Error number:  -2147024891 0x80070005
Access is denied. ```

Comment: You need to impersonate an account who has the permissions.

Comment: The credentials in question is part of the Administrators group.

Comment: The `Administrators` group on the remote computer, or `Administrators` in the domain they belong to?

Comment: Administrators group on the remote computer. The machines are not attached to a domain.

Comment: Can you perform the configuration in the blog if you login locally to one of your remote machines? If so, then you aren't actually running as the local admin of the remote machine. If not, then your admin account needs a permission or ACL which it doesn't have. Given the tone of the blog I'd guess your admin not having the permission or ACL means it was changed from the Windows default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Powershell will allow getting around the 150 MB limit (setting it to unlimited)

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WSMAN\Client -Name MaxMemoryPerShellMB -Value 0 -Type DWord
Restart-Service winrm
```